# How to Dynamic import of global css in Nextjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

when I am import global css in condition error comes
`An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a namespace or module.`

In _app.tsx

```
if (Cookies.get("theme") === "dark"){
    import "@/styles/core-dark.css";
    import "@/styles/theme-default-dark.css";
}else{
    import "@/styles/core.css";
    import "@/styles/theme-default.css"; 
}
```

it is not working can anyone suggest

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an `import` declaration. You could use the `import` function for dynamic behaviour.

```
if (Cookies.get("theme") === "dark") {
    await import("@/styles/core-dark.css");
    await import("@/styles/theme-default-dark.css");
} else {
    await import("@/styles/core.css");
    await import("@/styles/theme-default.css"); 
}
```

Note: If [top-level await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await) isn't supported, wrap the above statement inside and async IIFE

e.g

```
(async () => {
   if (Cookies.get("theme") === "dark") {
      await import("@/styles/core-dark.css");
      await import("@/styles/theme-default-dark.css");
   } else {
      await import("@/styles/core.css");
      await import("@/styles/theme-default.css"); 
   }
})()
```

Comment: when i use async method "Cannot find module '@/styles/core-dark.css' or its corresponding type declarations." is coming

Comment: Seems like a path error. Make sure the path to css file is a valid path. If it still doesn't work, try using a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and posted here

```
if (Cookie.get("theme") === "dark") {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = "/css/theme-default-dark.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(link);

        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = "/css/core-dark.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(link);
    }
} else {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = "/css/theme-default.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(link);

        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = "/css/core.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(link);
    }
}
```

I have use typescript and nextjs both and it work fine